# Custom email notification with link - sitecore

Tags: workflow, sitecore, sitecore7, email-notifications

I created a workflow as below, i want to send email with the link to the content approvers group when something is submitted? Can someone point me from where should i start with? which is the function that should be overridden ? Any help is appreciated

[image]

Thanks,

GT

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good example of how to create a custom workflow email that can be sent to users in a particular Sitecore role (and the user who last edited the content item).
http://techmusingz.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/workflow-notifications-in-sitecore-roles-and-users/

You can link to a specific content item in the Sitecore client using the following method but you need to already be logged in to the Sitecore client for this to work (Otherwise you are just directed to the Sitecore login page and won't be redirected to the item after login).

/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20Manager/default.aspx?fo={id}&la={language}&vs={version}&mo=preview

- fo - The item to open in the Sitecore client
- la - The language to open (optional)
- vs - The version to open (optional)
- mo - preview
  (optional)

Comment: Thank you..for link to content item can you direct me to a good example? I tried using Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(contentItem) is see something like this in the email /sitecore/shell/New Article Test.aspx but i want a actual URL so that onclick on it directs to the content.

Comment: You should be able to pass in UrlOptions like so: UrlOptions options = UrlOptions.DefaultOptions;
            options.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true;
And then do Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(contentItem, options)

Comment: This seems to generate the link something like this http:abc.com/sitecore/shell/New Article Test.aspx but when I click on the link it says document not found

Comment: /sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20Manager/default.aspx?fo={id}&la={language}&vs={version}&mo=preview when i use this with id passed i see the path to the content and when i attach the domain details and browse i am able to get to the content..but this gives jus the path not the complete url..what am i missing?