# GetFullUrl doesn't return the complete url - sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, fully-qualified-naming

I am trying to get a fully qualified url, here is the code

```
string path = string.Format("/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20Manager/default.aspx?id={0}&la={1}&fo={0}", contentItem.ID, contentItem.Language);

        string fullPath = Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.GetFullUrl(path);
        text = text.Replace("$itemUrl$", fullPath);
```

This returns something like this http://cp.localsite/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20Manager/default.aspx?id={DC6B4AE0-929D-4F19-97F4-825796A30781}&la=en&fo={DC6B4AE0-929D-4F19-97F4-825796A30781}
This is generated like a link till ?id=  from the id it looks like a normal text. How can i resolve this.I want clickable url for the content. I really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

could you please give a bit more context around what you are trying to achieve. The described behavior is correct, but it is obviously not what you were hoping to achieve.

UPDATED:

Looks like you are on the right track, the only thing i noticed is that you could really get away with just using the fo querystring to get to the right item, you could also use the other ones mentioned here [Custom email notification with link - sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219873/custom-email-notification-with-link-sitecore) to get more specific.

For the reason the url being cut off at the id= is that the text parser probably does not like the curly brakets - try encoding the URL and see if that works.

```
text = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text);
```

Comment: In the workflow step when a user submits content i am sending a email notification to the approvers. I am trying to send the content item link in the email. I tried several other ways as well, please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219873/custom-email-notification-with-link-sitecore

Comment: I tried encoding string path = string.Format("/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20Manager/default.aspx?id={0}&la={1}&fo={0}", contentItem.ID, contentItem.Language);
            string encodedPath = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(path);
            string fullPath = Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.GetFullUrl(encodedPath);
            text = text.Replace("$itemUrl$", fullPath); but this

Comment: continutation of the comment....link doesnt seem to work...comes out something like this  http://cp.localsite/%2fsitecore%2fshell%2fApplications%2fContent%2520Manager%2fdefault.aspx%3fid%3d%7bDC6B4AE0-929D-4F19-97F4-825796A30781%7d%26la%3den%26fo%3d%7bDC6B4AE0-929D-4F19-97F4-825796A30781%7d

Comment: I am trying to get to this link http://cp.localsite//sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20Manager/default.aspx?id={DC6B4AE0-929D-4F19-97F4-825796A30781}&la=en&fo={DC6B4AE0-929D-4F19-97F4-825796A30781} this is a working link